# How can I have php return specified number of characters in my result?

Tags: php, substr

Ive tried substr() but couldnt make it work. I just need $leadsmissed, $panswerrate, and $pcloserate to round to the nearest whole number and display that. I also need $prevenue to show the two digits past the decimal: xxx.xx

Am I missing something with the syntax of it? Im new to all this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
<?php
$branches  = $_POST['branches'];
$closerate  = $_POST['closerate'];
$ticketsize  = $_POST['ticketsize'];
$leadsperhour = .87;


$revenue = ($branches * $leadsperhour) * $closerate * $ticketsize;
$leadsmissed = $branches * $leadsperhour;

$panswerrate = .92 * $leadsmissed;

$pcloserate = $closerate * $leadsmissed;
$prevenue = $pcloserate * $ticketsize;


$result['string1'] = "Your company, on average, missed " . $leadsmissed . " leads in the   past hour. ";

$result['string2'] =  "With Pronexis, you would have talked to " .     $panswerrate . " of those leads, closed " . $pcloserate . " of them, and received $" . $prevenue . " more revenue!";



echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

Comment: Http://Php.net/number_format

Comment: Http://Php.net/round

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rounding to the closest integer number:

```
$leadsmissed = round($leadsmissed);
$panswerrate = round($panswerrate);
$pcloserate = round($pcloserate);
```

Convert to float with 2 decimals

```
$prevenue = number_format($prevenue , 2);
```